# Joystick.js on Unity project

Tags: airconsole

I just downloaded the UnityPackage to try AirConsole in my project, and I want to use the joystick controller example that is provided on GitHub. The problem here is that said joystick controller needs Joystick.js, and Unity tries to parse the file as Unity code...or at least that's what I think it's trying to do!

[image: Errors like these pop up.]

Any clue how to get rid of these unnecesary compilation errors?

Comment: dont post code as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript files that you want to use for the controller need to be in Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole, together with your controller file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you could put the Joystick.js into a script tag on your controller.html, then Unity won't compile it.